# HTML elements out of place while inspecting them

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, web-inspector

Here's a picture of the issue. Just picture my mouse as the painted red mouse as print screen does not capture the mouse.

For some reasons, the element is highlighted even though the mouse is not directly on it.

[image: My issue]

Has anyone experienced something like this? Any idea the issue could be over here?

**EDIT** 
Here's the code

```
    <div class="d-flex flex-column teamCard">
      <p class="teamCardHeading">Best performing teams</p>
      <div class="cardRow d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
        <BestTeamCardComponent />
        <BestTeamCardComponent />
        <BestTeamCardComponent />
        <BestTeamCardComponent />
        <BestTeamCardComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
```

---CSS-----

```
.teamCard {
  width: 992px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 32px 24px 32px 24px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.teamCardHeading {
  font-family: Averta-Bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #203767;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.cardRow {
  width: 992px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .cardRow,
  .teamCard {
    width: 345px;
  }

  .teamMetricRow {
    width: 300px;
  }

  .goalProgress,
  .progressBar,
  .progressMade {
    display: none;
  }

  .teamMetricRowPoints {
    transform: translateX(-0px);
  }
}
```

BestTeamCardComponent

```
<template>
  <div class="bestTeamMetric d-flex flex-column">
    <p class="bestTeamMetricHeading">{{title}}</p>
    <div
      v-for="(rec, index) in records"
      :key="index"
      :style="{backgroundColor: index % 2 == 1 ? 'white' : '#f7f8fb'}"
      class="d-flex flex-row teamMetricRow justify-content-around"
    >
      <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <p class="teamMetricRowTeam">{{rec.team}}</p>
        <p class="teamMetricRowMembers">{{rec.members}} members</p>
      </div>

      <p class="teamMetricRowPoints align-self-center">{{rec.points}}pts</p>

      <div class="d-flex flex-column align-self-center goalProgress">
        <div class="progressBar"></div>
        <div class="progressMade"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---CSS---

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.bestTeamMetric {
  width: 456px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.bestTeamMetricHeading {
  font-family: Averta;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #5c6170;
}

.teamMetricRow {
  width: 456px;
  //   height: 56px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.teamMetricRowTeam {
  font-family: Averta-Bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #203767;
}

.teamMetricRowMembers {
  font-family: Avenir;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #7e88a1;
}

.teamMetricRowPoints {
  font-family: Averta;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #203767;
}

.goalProgress {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
}

.progressBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 192px;
  height: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #f6f7ff;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

.progressMade {
  width: 120px;
  height: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #2ab2ff;
  border-radius: 32px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .bestTeamMetric {
    width: 345px;
  }

  .teamMetricRow {
    width: 300px;
  }

  .goalProgress,
  .progressBar,
  .progressMade {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

I literally don't know how but it's all working well now. There were some buttons that were being clicked around 100px above where they actually were, however they're also working now. I often run into obscure bugs... I didn't alter any CSS styles, it seems this was a browser web-inspecter/console issue